# Output rendered entity in twig template of views style plugin

Tags: views, 8, theming, plugins

How do I output a rendered entity of a taxonomy term in a views style row plugin template?

I am able to access the field `gamma` from the entity reference field `beta` of a row with the following code:

```
{{ row['#node'].beta.entity.gamma.value }}
```

but this taxonomy term has a complex rendering of its own fields, including images, through another template. I would like to utilize that effort here, if possible, instead of pulling out each field individually.

I was hoping something like:

```
{{ row.content.beta }}
```

would work, but it doesn't.

Guidance would be appreciated!

Edit: To clarify, the style template is something like this:

```
{# iterate rows #}
{% for row in rows %}
  {# create marker for each row #}
  {{ row }}
  {# get a row #}
  {% set last = row %}
{% endfor %}

{% if some_condition %}
  {# do something with one of the terms #}
  {{ last['#node'].beta }}
{% endif %}
```

I need access to one of the row's taxonomy terms, only if there is an exposed filter in effect, tested by "some_condition" through a preprocess function that parses the URL. I don't know if there's a better way of doing that, either, but it would all "work" if I could output the rendered term.

Comment: Views is mainly a UI tool, so I would start with configuring the output of the reference field using a custom view mode, where you select the fields you want to display and also get a template name suggestion for the term in that custom view mode.

Comment: If you install the Twig Tweak module it becomes quite easy: `{{ drupal_entity(‘taxonomy_term’, row['#node'].beta.entity.id, ‘teaser’) }}`

Comment: I do already have a custom view mode and template for the term. It works when the content is rendered elsewhere, but isn't invoked when accessing the field from the row.

I was hoping to avoid Twig Tweak, as I haven't yet had to rely on it for anything in this module.